# Angular 6 Error InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' when trying to access nested array

Tags: angular

I have this component code:

```
export class AddProductPropertiesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() product:  Observable<Product>;
  productProperties: ProductProperty[] = [];
  productProperty: ProductProperty = {
    propertyId: 0,
    propertyName: '',
    propertyValue: ''
  };
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  addProperty() {
    this.product.subscribe(prod => {
      prod.productPropertyList.push({
        propertyId: this.productProperty.propertyId,
        propertyName: this.productProperty.propertyName,
        propertyValue: this.productProperty.propertyValue
       });
    });
  }

  onRemoveProperty(propertyId) {
    this.product.subscribe(prod => {
      const index = prod.productPropertyList.findIndex(x => x.propertyId === propertyId);
      prod.productPropertyList.splice(index, 1);
    });
  }
}
```

And this html code for it:

```
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [ngModel]="(product | async)?.productPropertyList[in].propertyValue" name="propertyValue{{in}}" required  placeholder="مقدار" #propertyValue>
      </mat-form-field>

  <button  mat-button (click)='onRemoveProperty(property.propertyId)'><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>

</mat-list-item>
```

When I try to access productPropertyList in product object I get this error:

```
 InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

There is no problem in getting the information from services. I think the problem is with the way I'm using async. Besides there is no problem with the data in product object. Since I changed the product type to Observable I'm getting this error.

Comment: show us what are you passing in the @Input product?

Comment: there is no problem with data in the product object. Since I changed the product to Observable type I'm getting this error

Comment: Why are you `subscribe`ing to the `Observable` when you are unwrapping it in the template using an `async` pipe?

Comment: The reason I am asking is because product you are passing in the component has to be an observable. Is it an observable?

Comment: Oh!, actually it is not Observable. Please let me try it